# Программа не загадывает случайное число на python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа должна загадать число, а пользователь угадать это число. Я установил промежуток, чтобы программа загадывала число от 1 до 5.Где проблема? Почему не загадывает, а постоянно выводит неправильный ответ, как будто пользователь ошибается

```
print("Здарова! Тут короче правила игры - Угадай загаданное число! ")
from random import*
randint(1, 5)
s = input("Какие есть предложения?")
while s == randint:
    print("Ты угадал! Красавчик!")
else:
    while s != randint:
        print("Неверно!")
        s = input("Какие есть предложения?")
```

Comment: А что, по вашему, должно было произойти в `s == randint`? `s` -- это переменная с строкой, `randint` -- ссылка на функцию

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint

print("\nЗдравствуйте! Тут правила игры - Угадай загаданное число!\n")

x = randint(1, 5)
s = 1

while s:
    s = int(input("Какие есть предложения? "))
    if s == x:
        print("Вы угадал! Красавчик!\nПродолжаем игру (наберите `0` чтобы выйти).\n")
        x = randint(1, 5)
    else:
        if s: print("Неверно!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм:

- Загадываем число в `guessed_number`
- В цикле запрашиваем число от пользователя и сравниваем с `guessed_number`
- Выходим из цикла, в случае если тот угадал

```
from random import randint

print("Здарова! Тут короче правила игры - Угадай загаданное число! ")

guessed_number = randint(1, 5)

while True:
    s = input("Какие есть предложения?")
    if int(s) == guessed_number:
        print("Ты угадал! Красавчик!")
        break
    else:
        print("Неверно!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Главная проблема вашего кода заключается в том, что вы не положили случайное число в переменную и каждый раз оно генерировалось заново. Еще одна проблама - вложенные циклы. Как, зачем и почему, если можно сделать так? И напоследок - оформление, сначала стоит импортировать модули, а потом уже писать основную часть программы.

Удачи в изучении этого прекрасного языка! Вот решение вашей проблемы:

```py
from random import *

my_number = randint(1, 5)
print("Угадай загаданное число! ")
answer = int(input("Введите ответ: "))

while answer != my_number:
    print("Неверно!")
    answer = int(input("Введите ответ заново: "))
else:
    print("Ты угадал! Красавчик!")
```